# SQL Server Profiler - How to filter trace to only display events from one client?

Tags: sql-server-profiler, sql-server-2014

How do I limit a sql-server Profiler trace to a specific client? I can't see how to filter the trace to not see events for all clients on the instance I connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by client, you want the hostname or IP address of the specific client machine?  If you can't filter by username then I don't think this can be done using the filter built into profiler.

In SQL Server 2014 though, really you should be using extended events to do your tracing, and you definitely can use the client_hostname field to filter results to a single client machine.  Extended events realy isn't that difficult to use, especially in 2012+ with the GUI they added to it.